# How to use the android two line list item with a button?

Tags: android

The android design guidelines feature a range of list items which are encouraged to be used when designing android applications. The line items are featured in the building blocks section [here](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/lists.html). To me it is unclear however if there is a xml file or class which should be used to use these the line item with a button or if for this a custom xml should be created. Is this a build in functionality in the Android library or should it be build using custom xml files, i.e. how should the two line list items with a button be created?

[image: List view items in android]

Comment: For this you can use custom list view.Take look at this tutorial. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Thanks Akshay, I know how to create custom list view items. It just seems like a waste of time to recreate something with a custom XML file that is in the android design guidelines. Hence this question.

Comment: With the caveat that it's been deprecated in 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html for layout references API exposes publicly. Also see [TwoLineListItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TwoLineListItem.html). You have to design your own custom XML layout for your list item, there isn't one you can get from API.